# PD dataframe misteriously modified

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code is one of the blocks of my Data Science project notebook. "frame" is a dataframe and "graf4" is my attempt at copying frame and modifying it to get mt seasonal plot going.

However, each time a run this chunk of code, the values of the "frame" dataframe multiply by something like 3000, which doesn't make sense to me as, in my understanding, the code below never modifies "frame" and deletes "graf4" by it's end. What I'd expect was to see only my desired plot without modifications to 'frame'. As of now, the values of "price" in my plot are wrong and the cause seems to be some undesired change happening to the values of "price" column in the "frame" df happening in this chunk of code. I thank you in advance for your help in finding out what's wrong.

```
graf4 = frame

graf4['cost'] = graf4['price']*graf4['tickets']

graf4 = graf4.groupby(['month','year'], as_index=False).agg({'tickets':'sum', 'price':'sum'})

graf4['price'] = graf4['price']/graf4['tickets']

sns.lineplot(data=graf4, x='MES',y='TARIFA',hue='ANO')

del(graf4)

frame.head() #inserted to test the described mistake
```

as a note, the purpose of this chunk is to summarize an average price per ticket. Towards this goal I transformed the ticket prices to total cost of tickets by multiplying price and # of tickets before the groupby clause and I transform it back after the groupby clause by dividing the column by the number of tickets.

Comment: use `deepcopy` as `=` in python is shallow copy eg.`li2 = copy.deepcopy(li1)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538804/how-is-pandas-dataframe-handled-across-multiple-custom-functions-when-passed-as/62539198#62539198 Is also related. The issue is slightly more complicated. Sometimes you get **lucky** because many of the pandas operations create new objects so those operations will themselves break the shallow copy (i..e your groupby line doesn't modify frame, nor will anything after that line because the link is broken at that point)

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
graf4 = frame
```

you **don't** create a copy of the DataFrame but merely a new reference to the same object. So if you modify `graf4` this will also modify `frame`.

To create a copy of a DataFrame you can use the [DataFrame.copy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) method:

```
graf4 = frame.copy() # creates a copy of graf4 so frame will not be touched by any following actions
```

Comment: I commented the answer earlier, it is recommended to help users figure out the the simple small code anomalies by their own rather than spoon feeding them.

Comment: Everything isn't for upvotes and ratings :)